# Is it possible to share something into webapp?

Tags: javascript, php, android, html, google-chrome

I've created small webapp which is meant to be used as a shortcut for custom CMS I made earlier. Basically the CMS is responsive and could be placed on home screen. Specs here:
https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/installtohomescreen

Sometimes I need to add some content into that CMS using that webapp. I'm curious if it is possible somehow to integrate my webapp into Android's native share menu so I can just share e.g. link from native Twitter app into my webapp.

[image: AndroidShareMenu]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, no, this is a native Android function and you're going to have to create an Android app if you would like to do this.

Comment: Correct..you need to add it to your intents.

Comment: I thought so but I hoped it could be done somehow. :( Thanks for help.